# MYSQL: setting a model number based on the value of other fields in the set

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been given an odd task that I don't really agree with, but here it is:

I have a data set with over 2 million properties divided into over 40,000 subdivisions. Within each subdivision I'm supposed to generate a model number ascending based on living area DESC, bedroom DESC, bathroom DESC using only MySQL queries.

By this I mean that the largest model in a complex/subdivision is Model 1 the next largest is 2. If two are the same size the one with more bedrooms is next. If the living area and bedrooms are the same, then the bath count sets the next model number.

For example:

```
property id | complex id | Living area | Beds | Baths | Model (assigned)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1     |   A1       |    1900     | 3    |  2    |  1
      2     |   A1       |    1200     | 2    |  2    |  2
      3     |   A1       |    1200     | 2    |  2    |  2
      4     |   A1       |    1000     | 2    |  2    |  3
      5     |   A2       |    1500     | 3    |  2    |  2 
      6     |   A2       |    3500     | 6    |  4    |  1
      7     |   A2       |    1000     | 2    |  2.5  |  3
      8     |   A3       |    600      | 1    |  1.5  |  1
      9     |   A3       |    600      | 1    |  1    |  2    
      10    |   A3       |    500      | 1    |  1    |  3     
      11    |   A4       |    500      | 1    |  1    |  1      
      12    |   A5       |    2000     | 4    |  3    |  1      
      13    |   A5       |    1800     | 4    |  4    |  2      
      14    |   A5       |    1500     | 3    |  2    |  3      
      15    |   A5       |    1200     | 3    |  2    |  4      
      16    |   A5       |    1000     | 2    |  2.5  |  5      
      17    |   A5       |    800      | 2    |  2    |  6      
      18    |   A5       |    750      | 2    |  1    |  7      
      19    |   A5       |    750      | 2    |  1    |  7     
      20    |   A5       |    600      | 1    |  1    |  8      
      21    |   A5       |    600      | 1    |  1    |  8      
      22    |   A5       |    600      | 1    |  1    |  8
```

Using only  mysql, how might I assign model numbers in this way? Again, this is supposed to be done only using MySQL queries. I can write mysql functions, but may not use php, asp, c# etc.

Thanks for taking some time to try and solve this.

Comment: Are you wanting to manually execute several queries or trying to find a way to do this with a single query? If you cannot use any code, looping isn't possible so you are going to query 2 Million results all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I think it does what you want:

```
     select *, 
       if(@prevcomplex = complex_id, 
          if(@prevlayout = concat(living_area, ',', beds, ',', baths),
             @rank := @rank,
             if(@prevlayout := concat(living_area, ',', beds, ',', baths),
                @rank := @rank + 1,
                @rank := @rank + 1
             )
          ),              
          if(@prevcomplex := complex_id, 
             @rank := 1, @rank := 1)
       ) model 
  from data, (select @rank := 0)q 
  order by complex_id asc, living_area desc, beds  desc, baths desc;
```

There's a demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d10d85/10

Comment: That is amazing. Your mysqling puts me to shame. Thank you very much.